# Ajax post data collecting data with php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I'm a bit lost when it comes to posting data using Ajax. This is the code im using:

```
ajaxRequest.open("post", "serverTime.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(somedata);
```

Im not sure how i get hold of this data in my php script? How what i know what its called? is it just called 'somedata' Also what if i want to use multiple variables to pass through?

I think theres just something silly im over looking but i'm really struggling to find what im looking for on the internet

Thanks hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

```
// excerpt
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.send(params);
```

In get_data.php you can call them via `$_POST`:

```
echo $_POST['lorem']; // == ipsum
echo $_POST['name'];  // == binny
```

Example here: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/examples/ajax_using_post.php